# Is quantum gravity even detectable?

Tags: experimental-physics, quantum-gravity

Since gravity is several orders of magnitude weaker than the rest of the fundamental forces, the force of gravity acting on a single particle is almost *nonexistant. Since there is still a lot left for us to learn about gravity, is it possible that the force is fundamentally undetectable on a quantum scale? Does the Planck distance even correctly apply to this type of situation?

Comment: Related question: [Prospects for detection of gravitons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235603/)

Comment: [Semi-quantum gravity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/130665/44126).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prospects for detection of gravitons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235603/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking whether we can create gravitons in colliders or particle accelerators, the short answer is no.

Theoretically they could be detected, but in practice it is not possible, you will find this answer if you google Tony Rothman.

Gravitons interact with matter extraordinarily weakly. There is simply no physical equipment or experiment that could detect single gravitons.

The gravitational constant is so, that at the quantum level, it leads to a force, that is much weaker then the other fundamental forces.

But the weak and strong forces are short range forces, their strength decreases fast as you go bigger then the size of an atom. It is hard to build them (their forces) up into a macro force.

The EM force is long range like the gravitational. Why is the EM force still detectable at the quantum level? It has two poles, so at the macro level you will only see usually this attract or repel effect, or they will become neutral. Single electrons are detectable, and single photons are detectable, because they interact with matter at a level that we can detect with our experiments.

So to answer your question, it is very unlikely, that we will ever be able to detect single gravitons made in colliders.

Though, we are already able to detect GWs, but in that case, we are detecting basically the stretching in and out of spacetime itself. This is still not a way to detect gravity at a quantum level.

And to the strength of gravity at the Planck scale, I have asked the same question. But the reality is, that is just a theory, that gravity becomes strong at the Planck scale, there is no experimental evidence.

[Strong gravity at the micro level?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/421943/strong-gravity-at-the-micro-level?rq=1)